# Virtual box installations fails

Tags: ubuntu, installation, virtualbox

I have a problem with VirtualBox installation: it shows an error, saying that the install  conflicts with the installation package `VirtualBox-ose`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have been running VirtualBox OSE version 3 and you are trying to upgrade to VirtualBox 4 you will probably have to uninstall version 3 before installing version 4.

Certainly in Ubuntu the two versions use different package names, so a simple upgrade isn't possible.